# What is the C-Like Language CLL?

Tags: contract-development, history

There are some [older projects](https://github.com/jorisbontje/cll-sim), dated back to 2014 which develop contracts in CLL, C-Like Language. What is this and is this still being developed/used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CLL is both an acronym for "C-Like Language" and the name of an Ethereum high level language that eventually became Serpent. Vitalik described CLL as "the stripped-down-Python-like language in which you can write Namecoin in five lines of code" in [this blog post from February 2014](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/02/03/introducing-ethereum-script-2-0/). It is no longer being developed or used.

It was one of the earliest incarnations of the Ethereum high level smart contract languages we use today. An example of an Ethereum C-Like Language is Mutan.